# Role based permission to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do a role based permission control in a Laravel application. I want to check what actions can some user do, but i can't figure out how to implement gates and policies in my model (the permission description is in the database and are booleans asociated to a table that stores the resource's ids).

This is the database model that im using:

[image: Diagram]

I would like to know if [laravel gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization) is useful in my case, and how can i implement it, if not, how to make a basic middleware that take care of permission control to protect routes (or controllers).

In the table resource i have a uuid that identifies the resources, the alias is the name of the resource and has dot notation values of actions or context of the resource (eg. 'mysystem.users.create', 'mysystem.roles.delete', 'mysystem.users.images.view'). The policy tables has a boolean 'allow' field that describes the permission of users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should look at policies. For the whole group and role part, maybe use some reusable code as a trait or base class.

Comment: The role and group part have the same behaviour, but the precedence is: user specific permissions (most important), group permissions and role permissions (lessest important). I was thinking that i can generate the permission list adding the policies list from all the tables (keeping importance)

Answer (score 28):

This is the way that I implement role based permissions in Laravel using Policies.

Users can have multiple roles.
Roles have associated permissions.
Each permission allows a specific action on a specific model.

### Migrations

**Roles table**

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('label');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
// rest of migration file
```

**Permissions table**

```
class CreatePermissionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('label');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
// rest of migration file
```

**Permission Role Pivot Table**

```
class CreatePermissionRolePivotTable  extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
        });
    }
// rest of migration file
```

**Role User Pivot Table**

```
class CreateRoleUserPivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
        });
    }
// rest of migration file
```

### Models

**User**

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

public function assignRole(Role $role)
    {
        return $this->roles()->save($role);
    }

public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if (is_string($role)) {
            return $this->roles->contains('name', $role);
        }
        return !! $role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
    }
```

**Role**

```
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'label', 'description');
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }
    public function givePermissionTo(Permission $permission)
    {
        return $this->permissions()->save($permission);
    }
    /**
     * Determine if the user may perform the given permission.
     *
     * @param  Permission $permission
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasPermission(Permission $permission, User $user)
    {
        return $this->hasRole($permission->roles);
    }
    /**
     * Determine if the role has the given permission.
     *
     * @param  mixed $permission
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function inRole($permission)
    {
        if (is_string($permission)) {
            return $this->permissions->contains('name', $permission);
        }
        return !! $permission->intersect($this->permissions)->count();
    }
}
```

**Permission**

```
class Permission extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'label', 'description');
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
    /**
     * Determine if the permission belongs to the role.
     *
     * @param  mixed $role
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function inRole($role)
    {
        if (is_string($role)) {
            return $this->roles->contains('name', $role);
        }
        return !! $role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
    }
}
```

### Policies

A policy is required for each model.  Here is an example policy for a model `item`.  The policy defines the 'rules' for the four actions 'view, create, update, delete.

```
class ItemPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the item.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user)
    {
        $permission = Permission::where('name', 'items-view')->first();
        return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
    }
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create items.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        $permission = Permission::where('name', 'items-create')->first();
        return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
    }
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the item.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user)
    {
        $permission = Permission::where('name', 'items-update')->first();
        return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
    }
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the item.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user)
    {
        $permission = Permission::where('name', 'items-delete')->first();
        return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
    }
}
```

Register each policy in `AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
use App\Item;
use App\Policies\ItemPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Item::class => ItemPolicy::class,
    ];
// rest of file
```

### Controllers

In each controller, refer to the corresponding authorisation action from the policy.

For example, in the `index` method of `ItemController`:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->authorize('view', Item::class);

    $items = Item::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();

    return view('items', ['items' => $items]);
}
```

### Views

In your views, you can check if the user has a specific role:

```
@if (Auth::user()->hasRole('item-administrator'))
// do stuff
@endif
```

or if a specific permission is required:

```
@can('create', App\User::class)
// do stuff
@endcan
```

Comment: Hi. How can i define actions dinamically? all the actions (abilities) that a user can do are defined in my resource's table. But the `resolvePolicyCallback` method in the file `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate` calls the declared functions in the policy file, so i cant define functions dinamically in the ResourcePolicy class :(

Comment: Can you also provide the relationship from users model? hasRole() is missing currently.

Comment: @SarojShrestha I've updated it to include the relationship and `assignRole()` and `hasRole()` methods in the User model.

Comment: Great answer, please update to Laravel 7, in order to not lost relevancy

Comment: @kerrin in your Role->hasPermission method, you have `$this->hasRole($permission->roles);` where is this method `hasRole` created?

Comment: @digout the `hasRole()` method is on the User model, along with `roles()` and `assignRole()`.  I've included them above under Models.

Comment: @kerrin so shouldn't it be `$user->hasRole` not `$this->hasRole`

Answer (score 4):

**Answer for your Question**:*how to make a basic middleware that take care of permission control to protect routes (or controllers)?*.

**Just an Example:**
Here is the simple role middleware for your routes
**AdminRole**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;

class AdminRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->role->name!=="admin"){ //Check your users' role or permission, in my case only admin role for routes
            return redirect('/access-denied');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

After defining this middleware
Update your **kernel.php** file as

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ..............
    'admin' =>\App\Http\Middleware\AdminRole::class,
    ...................
];
```

And to use this route middleware:
There are different way to use route middleware but following is one example

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
});
```

**Note:** There are some tools and libraries for roles and permission on laravel but above is the example of creating basic route middle-ware.

Answer (score 1):

Because the laravel model did not fit my database so much, I did almost everything again. This is a functional draft in which some functions are missing, the code is not optimized and it may be a bit dirty, but here it is:

**proyect/app/Components/Contracts/Gate.php** This interface is used to create singleton in AuthServiceProvider.

```
<?php

namespace App\Components\Contracts;

interface Gate
{
    public function check($resources, $arguments = []);
    public function authorize($resource, $arguments = []);
}
```

**proyect/app/Components/Security/Gate.php** This file loads the permissions from the database. This could be improved a lot :(

```
<?php

namespace App\Components\Security;

use App\Components\Contracts\Gate as GateContract;
use App\Models\Security\Resource;
use App\Models\Security\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Gate implements GateContract
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    protected $container;
    protected $userResolver;
    protected $policies = [];

    public function __construct(Container $container, callable $userResolver)
    {
        $this->container    = $container;
        $this->userResolver = $userResolver;
    }

    public function permissionsForUser(User $user)
    {
        $result = User::with(['roles.resources', 'groups.resources', 'policies'])->where('id', $user->id)->first();

        $list = [];

        //role-specific ... the order is important role < group < user permissions
        foreach ($result->roles as $role) {
            foreach ($role->resources as $permission) {
                if (isset($list[$permission->uuid])) {
                    if ($list[$permission->uuid]['on'] == User::ROLE_POLICY) {
                        if ($permission->pivot->allow == false) {
                            $list[$permission->uuid]['allow'] = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $list[$permission->uuid]['allow'] = $permission->pivot->allow ? true : false;
                        $list[$permission->uuid]['on']    = User::ROLE_POLICY;
                        $list[$permission->uuid]['id']    = $role->id;
                    }
                } else {
                    $list[$permission->uuid] = [
                        'allow' => ($permission->pivot->allow ? true : false),
                        'on'    => User::ROLE_POLICY,
                        'id'    => $role->id];
                }
            }
        }

        // group-specific
        foreach ($result->groups as $group) {
            foreach ($group->resources as $permission) {
                if (isset($list[$permission->uuid])) {
                    if ($list[$permission->uuid]['on'] == User::GROUP_POLICY) {
                        if ($permission->pivot->allow == false) {
                            $list[$permission->uuid]['allow'] = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $list[$permission->uuid]['allow'] = $permission->pivot->allow ? true : false;
                        $list[$permission->uuid]['on']    = User::GROUP_POLICY;
                        $list[$permission->uuid]['id']    = $group->id;
                    }
                } else {
                    $list[$permission->uuid] = [
                        'allow' => ($permission->pivot->allow ? true : false),
                        'on'    => User::GROUP_POLICY,
                        'id'    => $group->id];
                }
            }
        }

        // user-specific policies
        foreach ($result->policies as $permission) {
            if (isset($list[$permission->uuid])) {
                if ($list[$permission->uuid]['on'] == User::USER_POLICY) {
                    if ($permission->pivot->allow == false) {
                        $list[$permission->uuid]['allow'] = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $list[$permission->uuid]['allow'] = $permission->pivot->allow ? true : false;
                    $list[$permission->uuid]['on']    = User::USER_POLICY;
                    $list[$permission->uuid]['id']    = $result->id;
                }
            } else {
                $list[$permission->uuid] = [
                    'allow' => ($permission->pivot->allow ? true : false),
                    'on'    => User::USER_POLICY,
                    'id'    => $result->id,
                ];
            }
        }

        return $list;
    }

    public function check($resources, $arguments = [])
    {
        $user = $this->resolveUser();

        return collect($resources)->every(function ($resource) use ($user, $arguments) {
            return $this->raw($user, $resource, $arguments);
        });
    }

    protected function raw(User $user, $resource, $arguments = [])
    {
        $list = $user->getPermissionList();

        if (!Resource::isUUID($resource)) {
            if (empty($resource = Resource::byAlias($resource))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (empty($list[$resource->uuid]['allow'])) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $list[$resource->uuid]['allow'];
        }
    }

  public function authorize($resource, $arguments = [])
    {
        $theUser = $this->resolveUser();

        return $this->raw($this->resolveUser(), $resource, $arguments) ? $this->allow() : $this->deny();
    }

   protected function resolveUser()
    {
        return call_user_func($this->userResolver);
    }
}
```

**proyect/app/Traits/Security/AuthorizesRequests.php** This file is added to controller. Allows to use `$this->authorize('stuff');` in a controller when is added.

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits\Security;

use App\Components\Contracts\Gate;

trait AuthorizesRequests
{
  public function authorize($ability, $arguments = [])
    {
        list($ability, $arguments) = $this->parseAbilityAndArguments($ability, $arguments);

        return app(Gate::class)->authorize($ability, $arguments);
    }
}
```

**proyect/app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php** This file is the same that can be found on `proyect/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php`, but i changed some parts to add new classe. Here are the important methods:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Components\Contracts\Gate as GateContract;
use App\Components\Security\Gate;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /* function register() ... */
    /* other methods () */

    protected function registerAccessGate()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(GateContract::class, function ($app) {
            return new Gate($app, function () use ($app) {
                return call_user_func($app['auth']->userResolver());
            });
        });
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

**proyect /app/Http/Middleware/AuthorizeRequest.php** This file is used to allow add the 'can' middleware to routes, eg: `Route::get('users/', 'Security\UserController@index')->name('users.index')->middleware('can:inet.user.list')`;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Components\Contracts\Gate;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

class AuthorizeRequest
{
    protected $auth;
    protected $gate;

    public function __construct(Auth $auth, Gate $gate)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->gate = $gate;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $resource, ...$params)
    {
        $this->auth->authenticate();
        $this->gate->authorize($resource, $params);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

but you must overwrite the default value in `proyect/app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
/* ... */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'can'        => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthorizeRequest::class,
    /* ... */
];
```

To use `@can('inet.user.list')` in a blade template you have to add this lines to `proyect/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
        Blade::if ('can', function ($resource, ...$params) {
            return app(\App\Components\Contracts\Gate::class)->check($resource, $params);
        });
    }
    /* ... */
```

**User model at proyect/app/Models/Security/User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Security;

use App\Components\Contracts\Gate as GateContract;
use App\Models\Security\Group;
use App\Models\Security\Resource;
use App\Models\Security\Role;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Notifiable;

    public $table = 'user';

    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';

    // tipos de politicas
    const GROUP_POLICY = 'group_policy';
    const ROLE_POLICY  = 'role_policy';
    const USER_POLICY  = 'user_policy';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
    ];

    public function policies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Resource::class, 'user_policy', 'user_id', 'resource_id')
            ->whereNull('user_policy.deleted_at')
            ->withPivot('allow')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'user_group', 'user_id', 'group_id')
            ->whereNull('user_group.deleted_at')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id')
            ->whereNull('user_role.deleted_at')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function getPermissionList()
    {
        return app(GateContract::class)->permissionsForUser($this);
    }
}
```

**Group model at proyect/app/Models/Security/Group.php** THis is the same than Role, change only names

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Security;

use App\Models\Security\Resource;
use App\Models\Security\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Group extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'group';

    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public static $rules = [
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function resources()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Resource::class, 'group_policy', 'group_id', 'resource_id')
            ->whereNull('group_policy.deleted_at')
            ->withPivot('allow')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Resource Model proyect/app/Models/Security/Resource.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Security;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Resource extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'resource';

    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
        'alias',
        'uuid',
        'type',
    ];

    public static $rules = [
    ];

    public static function isUUID($value)
    {
        $UUIDv4 = '/^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-4[0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i';

        return preg_match($UUIDv4, $value);
    }

    public static function byAlias($value)
    {
        return Resource::where('alias', $value)->first();
    }
}
```

There are a lot of things that I have not put here, but this is what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

The problem i find with trying to combine permissions from a db with policies is when it comes to the ownership of a record.

Ultimately in our code we would like to check access to a resource using permission only. This is because as the list of roles grows we don't want to have to keep adding checks for these roles to the codebase.

If we have a users table we may want 'admin' (role) to be able to update all user records but a 'basic' user to only be able to update their own user record. We would like to be able to control this access **SOLELY** using the database.

However, if you have an 'update_user' permission then do you give it to both roles?
If you don't give it to the basic user role then the request won't get as far as the policy to check ownership.

Hence, you cannot revoke access for a basic user to update their record from the db alone.
Also the meaning of 'update_user' in the permissions table now implies the ability to update **ANY** user.

**SOLUTION?**

Add extra permissions to cater for the case where a user owns the record.

So you could have permissions to **'update_user' AND 'update_own_user'**.

The 'admin' user would have the first permission whilst the 'basic' user would have the second one.

Then in the policy we check for the  'update_user' permission first and if it's not present we check for the 'update_own_user'.

If the 'update_own_user' permission is present then we check ownership. Otherwise we return false.

The solution will work but it seems ugly to have to have manage 'own' permissions in the db.